# What build tool can i use with artifactory community for .net projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

Right now my boss made a simple plugin to integrate maven with .net projects, but this keeps us from doing certain things. I want to propose a non-maven solution, and would love to use nuget with artifactory but the pro version isnt cheap. Is there a different build solution I can use that integrates well with artifactory and jenkins?

I looked into gradle and Ivy,  but .net still seems like a second class citizen there.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use the nuget support in the Pro version. 
You can evaluate it for free before deciding on paying any money at all, and then you can use the [cloud-based Artifactory instance](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorycloud_overview) and pay per month per use if that's easier than paying for a year in front.

Comment: I appreciate your reassurance that artifactory pro is solid, but convincing my boss to use nuget instead of our hackish .net plugin for maven is going to be real hard when the alternative is to pay 3k. The cloud services are a reasonable idea, but my company is a little knee jerk with that, after a terrible AWS experence. +1 for usefulness, but it doesnt answer the question